# How to make python server auto redirect to home page instead of giving file list?

Tags: python, redirect

I am quite new to python and I could not find an answer to my question on SO...

I have a server that is based on simple python server.
The actually html file is at:

```
/front/home.html
```

So say I am deploying the server at port 8080, if I type localhost:8080, it will show a page with list of files. I will have to click front->home.html to see my frontpage.

My problem is: how do I get the server to auto redirect to front/home.html when I enter localhost:8080? I suppose this cannot be done from the javascript side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build a simple web application? Have you looked into using a tiny framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to help you do this? With Flask, what you want is only a few lines of code :)

Create a file named `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('front/home.html')

if __name__ = '__main__':
   app.run()
```

And you could run this with

```
 python app.py
```

And access it via the default location of `http://localhost:5000`

Cool, no?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking switching to web.py or other frameworks at appropriate time. But is there a way to do this with pure python?

Comment: Sure, you could use something like the `wsgiref` module, but in all honesty, the benefits of using a micro framework like Flask outweigh trying to stay pure, atleast in my opinion :) http://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html